# Selecting other branch instead of master as a source repository on AWS CodeBuild

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

How to specify different branch instead of `master` branch on AWS code deploy while using `Github` as source provider ? I see there is no option to select in the console to select branch(may be I missed).

I tried to checkout to different branch while we are in the `pre_build` phase, but it failed in the **Download Source** phase itself as the `master` branch doesn't have YAML file.

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - apt-get update -y
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - git checkout testbranch
```

Comment: `aws-codebuild` will be a prefect tag for this, but I don;t have enough rep to create it.

Comment: Can you please post complete answer? accepted answer is not working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can specify the branch in the "source version" field when you start a build.  It will accept anything that "git checkout" accepts: commit ID, branch, tag, etc.

Comment: Where is this source version field, I'm unable to find?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it only accepts commit ids

Comment: @ClareLiguori It started working. I think it was that i was using 'enter key' after typing the branch instead of clicking in continue below.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.  branches are ok, but tags or ids don't work. Issue raised [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=330129)

Comment: I just entered branch name in Source version but the build is triggering even I am pushing codes on different branch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default branch (when not supplying a version in the individual build) from master to something else you have to use the AWS CLI as there is apparently no option in the UI:

```
aws codebuild update-project --name your_project_name --source-version your_default_branch
```

Adding a new source version at build time will still override this value per the docs:

> If sourceVersion is specified at the project level, then this sourceVersion (at the build level) takes precedence.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_StartBuild.html#CodeBuild-StartBuild-request-sourceVersion